# How to order by a property of a collection of a collection (collections chain)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql

Suppose I have this Java class hierarchy:

```
class Product {
    @OrderBy(“?”)
    List<Subcategory> subcategories;
}

class Subcategory {
    String subcategoryName;
    List<Category> categories;
}

class Category {
    String categoryName;
}
```

How can I use `@OrderBy` to order products by `categoryName` of `Category` class?
I was imagining something like:

```
@OrderBy("categories[].categoryName ASC")
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work that way.

Comment: So, you want to order product1 with category names ["Animals", "Zoology"] and product2 with category names ["Botany", "Gardening"]. Which goes first?

Comment: Let's assume the first one because it has an element that does before all elements of all other products

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible, but also, why would you need that? Anyway, you can implement a custom `Comparator` for this purpose and sort the list in a `@PostLoad` listener.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I needed it because I wanted to do it using SQL and not in Java for performance reasons.

Comment: You are loading the whole collection anyways so there is no real performance gain. The only case where sorting on the database makes a difference is when you also paginate the data.